# jQuery's $.each() displays only the first character of each index

Tags: jquery

Good day guys,

Please, I don't know what I am not doing right...

I am trying to loop through an array in jQuery and my code is as show below:

```
var l = [], quantity = [], all = [];
        
$.each($(data),function(key,value){
   l[key] = value.product[key];
   quantity[key] = parseInt(value.quantity[key]);
   all[key] = {y:quantity[key], label:l[key]};
})

console.log('All :'+JSON.stringify(all));
```

I decided to console log the result just to be sure, but instead of getting the correct answer console-logged, what I saw was rather confusing...

**Below is the console-logged result:**

```
All :[{"y":6,"label":"P"},{"y":null,"label":"a"}]
```

**And this is the expected result:**

```
All :[{"y":632.91,"label":"Petrol"},{"y":1.0,"label":"Gas"}]
```

**Meanwhile, this is the structure of my data:**

```
[{amount: '1089750.00', quantity: '6604.61', product: 'Petrol', mon: '2022-02-25'},{amount: '200.00', quantity: '0.46', product: 'Kerosene', mon: '2022-02-25'},{amount: '600.00', quantity: '1.00', product: 'Gas', mon: '2022-03-01'}]
```

Please, any contribution, suggestion or recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `l[key] = '"'+value.product[key]+'"';` followed by `l[key] =  l[key].replace(/["']/g, "");`??? You're *adding* quotes only to remove them one line later?

Comment: We don't know what `value` is supposed to be but `value[key]` seems wrong - why would you need to index *the value* with the key? With `key = 0; value = "hello"` that would produce `"h"`. I'm not sure that's really what's intended. Then again, we don't know the shape of the data.

Comment: without seeing what data looks like, we can only guess. but maybe you can just do `$.each(data, function(key, value) { all[key] = { y: value.quantity, label: value.product };})`

Comment: @VLAZ I have updated the question to include the data structure

Comment: Right, so `value[key]` is indeed incorrect.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

That is because `$.each` has different signature (see [docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)). It is `$.each(data, function (index, element)` which is why you have first letter from "Petrol" and second letter from "Gas" in the labe property

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help

```
<script> 
    let data = [{amount: '1089750.00', quantity: '6604.61', product: 'Petrol', mon: '2022-02-25'},{amount: '200.00', quantity: '0.46', product: 'Kerosene', mon: '2022-02-25'},{amount: '600.00', quantity: '1.00', product: 'Gas', mon: '2022-03-01'}]

        var l = [], quantity = [], all = [];
        
        console.log(data);
        $.each($(data),function(key,value){ 
           l[key] = value.product;
           quantity[key] = parseInt(value.quantity);
           all[key] = {y:quantity[key], label:l[key]};
        })
        
        console.log('All :'+JSON.stringify(all));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) { all[key] = { y: value.quantity, label: value.product };})
```

Credit: Carsten Løvbo Andersen